# difference between calling and executing stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure using a table in the server. I had originally created the procedure and executed it a month back. The table that is used in the SP has been updated. So i want to call the SP again. Is the way to do that is to execute it again like i did a month ago, right cluck on the SP and click 'Execute Stored PRocedure...' or is there another way of calling it?

Comment: `EXECUTE` is the way you run a procedure, yes.

Comment: *If* it is the first statement in the batch, then you can also omit the `EXEC(UTE)`, however, I'm not personally a fan of such syntax.